# SSL Server getting error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

i had installed python,pip,aws cli and boto in my 12.04 05 LTS client desktop. And i  have downloaded the domjudge ami file to my pc from the following link https://github.com/ubergeek42/domserver-ami. And changed ‘baseami’ and ‘region in the createami.py file ,after that i tried to running this script unfortunately i got an error like some SSL server getting error. The details steps images are attached with this mail

1) My python version
[image]

2) Then we installed the Boto package via pip using the following command
     sudo pip install boto

3) To test that Boto has successfully installed into our environment 
[image]

4) Then i provided the following details through aws configure command

AWS Access Key ID,
AWS Secret Access Key ,
Default region name,
Default output format

5) Finally i tried to run the createami.py i got the following error
[image]

So kindly suggest how can i solve this problem

Comment: I think I have met a similar error once, if i remember well I updated the  Requests package and that worked (not sure about this though, this is quite long time ago). Could you isolate and share the part of your code that is crashing?

Comment: Now i shifted to open network and my problem is resolved.The reason is i am working under the domain network so here firewalls blocked some requests